# Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges conditionally, $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ could diverge to 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This post follows from [Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges conditionally or diverges to 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784877/577710).

There we haven't proved he following statement (particularly with my **proof 2**, we even seem to disprove it) that

> if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges conditionally, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^2$ converges not, $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ diverges to $0$.

Any idea about ways to prove that? (Or to point out what goes wrong in my **proof 2** that leads to the negation of the above statement.)

Comment: Diverges to 0???? It's new to me, is there any definition of this!

Comment: @Subhajit Yes. An infinite product of complex numbers diverges to $0$ if the limit of the partial products is $0$.

Comment: @Subhajit When an infinite product is equal to $0$ this is usually called divergence, not convergence. If you think about it, this makes sense, since there might be examples where the product equals to $0$ because the first term is $0$, then the other terms are simply irrelevant.

Comment: @Subhajit The main reason is that you want the assertion "$\prod_n (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_n \log (1+a_n)$ converges" to make the most sense it can.

Comment: @Gae. S. and @Mark; thanks to both.

Comment: @Charlie Chang I think ,it would help;https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712825/does-infinite-product-prod-1-frac12n-diverge-to-0-or-converge

Comment: An "example of a counterexample" is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731650).

Comment: I will use the example to check the proof and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem in my *proof 2* in [Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges conditionally or diverges to 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784877/577710) is since we have 'for all p, ...<$\epsilon$', then *$\epsilon$ should be independent of* p, but in my proof it is not!

More specifically, $\epsilon$ there depends on x only, not p, (so p depends not on $\epsilon$) so however small $\epsilon$ is, we can choose p sufficiently large, e.g. 1/$\epsilon$-1, so that
$\epsilon'+\epsilon|M|(p+1)$ can't be arbitrarily small, e.g. it being larger than $|M|$.